# Failed to pass html input to django

Tags: python, html, django, django-request

I'm trying to pass date input to django python script in order to retrieve the data based on it.

Here is my code.

view

```
def daily_usage_report(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_date = request.POST.get('request_date')
    else:
        request_date = date.today()

    print(request_date)
...
```

html

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="date" name="request_date" id="request_date">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{% url 'daily_usage_report' %}" style="color: white;">Daily Usage Report</a></button>
    </form>
```

I tried to fill the form with random date, but it keeps printing today date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html should be looking like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'daily_usage_report' %}">
    <input type="date" name="request_date" id="request_date">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the python script file in the POST form method action in your HTML script.

```
<form method="post" action="python_script_goes_here.py">
        <input type="date" name="request_date" id="request_date">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{% url 'daily_usage_report' %}" style="color: white;">Daily Usage Report</a></button>
</form>
```